# How can I get rid of 700 million tons of chlorine gas?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, environmental-chemistry, applied-chemistry, green-chemistry

I am conducting a thought experiment in which 40 million tons of hydrogen are supplied through saltwater electrolysis each year, creating 700 million tons of chlorine gas (Cl2) and 800 million tons of sodium hydroxide. (Lye)

I think I can get rid of a good chunk of the sodium hydroxide by mixing it with nitric acid and creating sodium nitrate for use as substitute for ammonium nitrate fertilizer, but I am not sure on how to get rid of the chlorine gas.

Comment: Well, if you're allowed to use anything you like, just react it with sodium metal and enjoy a lifetime's supply of table salt...

Comment: Just sell it.  It is used in industry.

Comment: This is a follow-on to a previous question http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49346/will-hydrofluorosilicic-acid-react-with-chlorine-gas

Comment: Simply, sell it (Javel water!)

Comment: Current world production of chorine is about 100m tonnes per year. You would seem to be creating a gross surplus. Perhaps giving everyone in the world clean water and lots of sodium hypochlorite would be a start. Or you could make a lot of PVC and distribute it free.

Comment: Why not go one step further, you could react the chlorine with the sodium hydroxide to get NaCl + NaOCl and if there's a way of somehow separating the two you can get a lifetime's supply of table salt AND water disinfectant :D

Comment: Let the electrolysis produce oxygen instead of chlorine.

Comment: mattblack you are correct, this would produce a tremendous surplus of chlorine and sodium hydroxide.  Poly Vinyl Carbonate is a good use for it, but even so, the demand is limited.  Water Treatment is also a good option.  Orthocresol, this is a good idea, but then what would you do with all that bleach?  aventurin, even with a catalyst, the rate and efficiency of hydrogen production using distilled water is very slow and inefficient.

Comment: @orthocresol That would be a lot of energy!!!